# Can a telegram bot change a supergroup from private into public?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've been using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and I want my telegram bot to change supergroup's type from public into private, but I'm not able to find any api about this. Can anyone tell me is it possible to make a telegram bot to change supergroup's type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all.

This is not related to your programming language. This is because Telegram Bot API doesn't support your desired operation.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't 
You only can subscribe to group change checking `migrate_from_chat_id` and `migrate_to_chat_id` in messages inside channel. Unfortunately you can't init such changes from bot, only observation possible and could be handled with fields mentioned above.